# rpi-update seemed to have stopped spi and one wire

Tags: kernel, spi, update, firmware, rpi-update

I had two programs, one using DS18b20 sensors and the One-Wire and the other using SPI. On another pi, I had a program using the camera which had an error(still not sure what the error was) fixed by rpi-update. I wanted to run the three programs fro one pi so I used rpi-update and the two programs stopped working

My boot/config.txt file has

## NOOBS Auto-generated Settings:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
start_x=1
gpu_mem=144
dtparam=spi=on

dtoverlay=spi-bcm2708
dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup, gpiopin=17
```

But /sys/bus/w1/devices/ shows no temperature sensors but this instead

```
00-740000000000  00-f40000000000  w1_bus_master1
```

lsmod show

```
Module                  Size  Used by
binfmt_misc             7988  1 
bnep                   12051  2 
hci_uart               20020  1 
btbcm                   7916  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             365511  22 hci_uart,bnep,btbcm
brcmfmac              222874  0 
brcmutil                9092  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              543027  1 brcmfmac
snd_bcm2835            24427  3 
rfkill                 20851  4 bluetooth,cfg80211
snd_pcm                98501  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              23904  1 snd_pcm
snd                    70032  9 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
bcm2835_gpiomem         3940  0 
w1_gpio                 4818  0 
wire                   32619  1 w1_gpio
cn                      5889  1 wire
fixed                   3285  0 
uio_pdrv_genirq         3923  0 
uio                    10204  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                 6913  0 
fuse                   99603  3 
ipv6                  408587  32
```

/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf doesn't exist

and /etc/modules only shows i2c-dev

I updated and upgraded the system as well. Would ideally not like to downgrade the rpi-update

sudo vcdbg log msg shows

```
001778.709: Failed to load overlay 'spi-bcm2708'
001800.541: Loaded overlay 'w1-gpio-pullup'
001800.557: dtparam:  gpiopin=17
001804.215: Unknown dtparam ' gpiopin' - ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911

Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."
`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much! Had no idea about that. Noted for the future That seems to have fixed the SPI. But any idea about the 1-wire? Edited the question to include more about that bit.

Comment: Never mind! Seems like removing the spaces in the line "dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup, gpiopin=17" fixed it. Strange that it's been working for weeks with that. But thanks so much again!

Comment: many many thanks!!!! the space between w1-gpio-pullup, gpiopin=17 costed me many days, and motivation! now it works thx!