# SPI6 on RPi4B does not load

Tags: spi

I've got problem with load SPI6 on RPI4B.
What I did is:

1. enabling SPI interface in Raspberry Pi Configuration
2. checking in `/etc/modules` whether there is `spi-dev` (I added manually)
3. (based on README in `/boot/overlay`), in the `config.txt` added

   dtoverlay=spi6-1cs,cs0_pin=26,cs0_spidev=on

   dtoverlay=anyspi:spi6-0,dev="STM,lis3dh",speed=10000000

Result:
I can't find device spidev6.0 in /dev

4. I tried with rebooting in any combination, but nothing worked
5. re-installed bootloader and kernel following by post [rpi-update seemed to have stopped `spi` and one wire](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68017/rpi-update-seemed-to-have-stopped-spi-and-one-wire)

I also tried `dtoverlay` from the command line, according to[Raspberry Pi 4 - Multiple SPIs](https://blog.stabel.family/raspberry-pi-4-multiple-spis-and-the-device-tree/)
I can load any SPI from # = 0 to 6 using command

```
sudo dtoverlay spi#-1cs
```

Any `spi` from 0 to 5 can be loaded (I checked using `dtoverlay -l`), but `spi6` brings error:

```
Failed to apply overlay '0_spi6-1cs' (kernel)
```

The same result is for `spi6-2cs`
What's the problem? Can anyone help?
Would this problem relate to the issue [in this post](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/pull/3262)?

I tried to use spi1 instead of spi6, because it shares the same pins. But I need it for LIS3DH accelerometer which requires `spi.mode=3`. Here was another problem that this mode is not supported by spi1 [I found this here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106456/cant-set-modes-1-and-3-in-auxillary-spi1/120465#120465). Then I wanted to check if `spi6` can work in `mode=3`.
I am newbie, so maybe I am making a simple mistake...hmm...

Comment: when I successfully enable spi6 using `sudo dtoverlay spi6-1cs cs0_pin=16` as per the instructions in the link, there is no `/dev/spidev6.0` - but there is `/dev/spidev3.0` - it seems the first spi enabled over 2 gets spidev3, the second spidev4 etc, so if the first spi over 2 that you enable is spi6, in /dev it will be `/dev/spidev3.?`

Comment: perhaps one of GPIO's 19,20,21 is in use by something else in your system